# How to select rows with multiple condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select some rows with multiple conditions. I would like to even if one of the conditions was true then that row was selected.

[image]

```
def obtain(x):
    mask = (x['EucDistPoint'] >= x['EucDistPoint'].mean()) | (x['CRS'] >= 
            x['CRS'].mean()) | (x['CRC'] >= x['CRC'].mean())
    selected = x.loc[mask]
    return selected
selected = data.groupby('MMSI').apply(obtain)
```

I want the output row to have at least one of the conditions but in output, I have the rows that haven't any of these conditions.

I've applied :

```
def obtain(x):
    mask = (x.EucDistPoint >= x.EucDistPoint.mean()) |\
        (x.CRS >= x.CRS.mean()) | (x.CRC >= x.CRC.mean())
    return x[mask]
selected = data.groupby('MMSI').apply(obtain)
```

but when I want to check the output I use this:

```
selected[selected['MMSI']==210161000].min()
```

but the output is like this:

```
MMSI                        210161000
BaseDateTime      2017-02-01 08:54:35
LAT                           34.2080
LON                         -125.9994
SOG                            1.1000
COG                         -194.3000
CRS                            0.0000
CRC                            0.0000
X                         230030.4090
Y                        3789274.2135
EucDistPoint                   0.0000
HaverDistPoint                 0.0000
dtype: object
```

and this is wrong because the minimum of CRS and CRC and EucDistPoint are 0.0022, 0.0446 and 551.887

Comment: Can you add some example data, 5-10 rows.  For example `print(x.head(10))` and add that to your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: I did . now you can see @Erfan

Comment: Please, do not post data as image. Have a look at [*How to make good reproducible pandas examples*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Its in your jupyter notebook. Simply do `print(selected)` and post that output in your question.

Comment: And what is the reason you use `groupby` here?

Answer (score 1):

Your code works "as is". You can also write it a bit shorter:

```
def obtain(x):
    mask = (x.EucDistPoint >= x.EucDistPoint.mean()) |\
        (x.CRS >= x.CRS.mean()) | (x.CRC >= x.CRC.mean())
    return x[mask]
data.groupby('MMSI').apply(obtain)
```

**Example**

My source DataFrame:

```
        MMSI  CRS     CRC  EucDistPoint
0  210161100  1.0  1.0000           0.0
1  210161100  0.0  0.0281         200.0
2  210161100  0.0  0.0530         589.1
3  210161200  1.0  1.0000           0.0
4  210161200  0.0  0.0281         500.0
5  210161200  0.0  0.0530         200.1
```

Mean values (`data.groupby('MMSI').mean()`):

```
                CRS       CRC  EucDistPoint
MMSI                                       
210161100  0.333333  0.360367    263.033333
210161200  0.333333  0.360367    233.366667
```

Conditions for particular columns (`df.groupby('MMSI').transform(lambda x: x >= x.mean())`):

```
             CRS    CRC  EucDistPoint
MMSI                                 
210161100   True   True         False
210161100  False  False         False
210161100  False  False          True
210161200   True   True         False
210161200  False  False          True
210161200  False  False         False
```

As you can see, row No 1 and 5 have *False* in all 3 columns (row
numbers from 0), so they should not be in the output.

And the result of either your or my function:

```
                  MMSI  CRS     CRC  EucDistPoint
MMSI                                             
210161100 0  210161100  1.0  1.0000           0.0
          2  210161100  0.0  0.0530         589.1
210161200 3  210161200  1.0  1.0000           0.0
          4  210161200  0.0  0.0281         500.0
```

Just as it should be.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. your output is the same that I want. I added my output to my question. can you please tell me why my output and your output are different?

Comment: My output is correct. I found out where is my mistake.